# Magento 2 : on page load product sorting not working

Tags: magento2, sorting, product-sorting

When I go on the category page, sorting does not work unless I select any value from dropdowns like position or price then it sorts the product. 
http://prntscr.com/q97trw

Can anyone help me how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to sort product on loading ?

Comment: Sorting works on ajax , so you need to call that on load.

Comment: Yes Hiren i want it on loading

Comment: I have checked, when open page position is set on dropdonw and check first 3 prodcuts. When i change sorting price and select again position, same product display. So it looks default sorting position is working

Comment: user55548 when first page loads its not show correct sorting unless we change the order from dropdown.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Did anyone have the fix?